# Python pd.read_csv don't understand why adding comma

Tags: python, csv, github, streamlit

I'm deploying a streamlit app' and when I import a CSV file, I don't understand why there are comma separator.

Here there is my pd.read_csv instructions (X_train importation). I didn't change anything but don't understand why the comma appears

```
@st.experimental_singleton
def load_dataset():
# On charge le dataset d'entrainement
X_train = pd.read_csv("X_train.csv", index_col=0)
y_train = pd.read_csv("Y_train.csv", index_col=0)
categories = pd.read_csv("categories.csv", sep="\t", decimal=',')
```

Notice that I've already run the streamlit in the local way and it works fine. I have this result for "productid", and "imageid" columns

[image]

Unfortunately, when I run from my github repo, I have some comma and don't know how to remove them.

[image]

link of my repo : https://github.com/m-moriss/Data_challenge_RAKUTEN

Anyone know how to fix that ? I'v tried so many way to import but it didn't works.

Comment: The number is just being formatted differently due to e.g. a different locale setting; it's still just a number in the dataframe. What is the problem you're having with having that comma in there?

Comment: The fact is that it's not quantitative information because it's a code. I have to deploy the app for an application and it's not good if I leave this like that. For example, in France there is a Zip code for each city. Even if it is a number, it doesn't make sens to put comma in this.

Comment: Then cast the column to a string type.